# Autocorrelation scatterplot for a special lag

Tags: r

I am using `acf` function to calculate Autocorrelation. I want to have a scatter plot for a special lag for example lag 2. Does it possible to do it with `acf` function.

Is there any package that help me to have a scatter plot for each lag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
lag.plot1=function(data1,max.lag=1,corr=TRUE,smooth=FALSE){ 
   name1=paste(deparse(substitute(data1)),"(t-",sep="")
   name2=paste(deparse(substitute(data1)),"(t)",sep="")
   data1=as.ts(data1)
   max.lag=as.integer(max.lag)
   prow=ceiling(sqrt(max.lag))
   pcol=ceiling(max.lag/prow)
   a=acf(data1,max.lag,plot=FALSE)$acf[-1]
  par(mfrow=c(prow,pcol), mar=c(2.5, 4, 2.5, 1), cex.main=1.1, font.main=1)
  for(h in 1:max.lag){                       
   plot(lag(data1,-h), data1, xy.labels=FALSE, main=paste(name1,h,")",sep=""), ylab=name2, xlab="") 
    if (smooth==TRUE) 
    lines(lowess(ts.intersect(lag(data1,-h),data1)[,1],
                 ts.intersect(lag(data1,-h),data1)[,2]), col="red")
    if (corr==TRUE)
    legend("topright", legend=round(a[h], digits=2), text.col ="blue", bg="white", x.intersp=0)
   }
}

lag.plot1(dat,12,smooth=TRUE)
```

[image]

The full call is `lag.plot1(x,m,corr=TRUE,smooth=TRUE)` and it will generate a grid of scatterplots of `x(t-h)` versus`x(t)` for h = 1,...,m, along with the `autocorrelation` values in `blue` and a `lowess fit in red`.If you don't want any correlations or lines, simply use `R's lag.plot`

```
library(forecast)
lag.plot(LakeHuron,lags=3,do.lines=FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: very nice, very nice...could you please explain me how you generate the red line, and why is this line curve? thnks a lot

Comment: `?lowess` : This function performs the computations for the LOWESS smoother which uses locally-weighted polynomial regression